# Android USB Accessory intent filter, don't want it to auto-launch app

Tags: android, android-intent, usb

I am trying to use USB Accessory in my app.  It works well, but I have a problem.

If I put USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED intent-filter in my manifest, then the app auto launches when the device gets plugged in.  This is would be fine, but sometimes when I unplug the device and plug it back in then the app launches a 2nd time.

Fine, I really don't want it to auto-launch so I removed the intent-filter.  Removing the intent-filter works the best, but it asks for user permission each time and ignores the 'use by default for this USB accessory' checkbox.

Is there a way to use an intent-filter and not have the app auto start?

Why is my app auto-starting when I already have an app running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to stop the app from launching a second time when the USB connects by changing the activity's android:launchMode setting in the manifest.

I changed launchMode to "singleTop".

All the tutorials that discuss Android Accessory and intent filters, none of them mentioned the launchMode setting.  Seems like an obvious oversight on all the people who write those tutorials, including Google, when it has a big impact on how Android Accessory and intent filters work.

Comment: What did you change the launch mode to?

Comment: @tmalseed, sorry for the late response.  I changed launchMode to "singleTop".

Comment: did not work for me, I still get the activity to be launched when I connect the usb @TimMalseed